# C# Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from int[] to int

Tags: c#

When i try to display the item from the array it brings up this: Error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from int[] to int

```
    List<int[]> rolls = new List<int[]>();
    rolls.Add(new int[] { throw1, throw2, throw3 }); 


    Console.WriteLine(rolls[rolls[1]]);
```

Comment: Isn't that `rolls[throw2]`?

Comment: you don't have a rolls[1]. you have a list rolls that contains one element (i.e. rolls[0]) and that element is {throw1, throw2, throw3}.

Comment: @andrewf Still brings up the same error upon changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to index into the list using a reference to an array.
when you write `rolls[rolls[1]]`, `rolls[1]` is an *array*, not an int. An int is what is expected when you index into an the list (i.e. when you do rolls[x]) where x is some int.  Also, as others have pointed out, since rolls only contains one element, `rolls[1]` would be an index that is out of bounds.
What would work would be something like this :

```
Console.WriteLine(rolls[0][0]) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the compilation error, I **assume** you are trying to pull an element from the array (which is inside the List).

E.g.,

```
List<int[]> rolls = new List<int[]>();
rolls.Add(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

to fetch an element from the above array (as per your code), use

```
rolls[0][0]
```

first '[0]' will fetch the element at '0th' index from List (in this case it is int[]) and the next index '[0]' will fetch the '0th' element from int[].